# Is RSA encoded block considered good random distributed?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I am creating a new transmission protocol, and I currently use a lot of RSA transfers that send a AES key to protect the data.

My current setup for a packet is:

```
RSA_Block{
   AES key
   IV
   Other things
}
AES_Block{
   Data
}
```

The problem is that the IV itself takes space inside the secure RSA block. If I move the IV out (which is fine from security point of view) takes some extra space in my transfers (enlarges the packet by IV size).
So I am thinking.... if the RSA block contains pure random data (the AES key is random at every transmission). I use the first part of the RSA encoded block as IV.

But is it secure? Or does the RSA block have some non randomness in its first bytes?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying, and your statements about the IV don't make sense to me. However, it almost sounds like you are looking for something like [RSA-KEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation). Give it a read.

Comment: I believe it is not, I think I remember that it is possible to extract at least 1 bit of information about the plain text from the cipher text in RSA, but I can't find a reference right now. But as for everything related to crypto: if you're not sure, don't do it.

Comment: However, if you use a fresh random AES key for every transmission, you don't need an IV at all. IV's are useful to not obtain the same cipher text twice, which you don't get because you don't reuse the key.

Comment: Instead of thinking about where the IV comes from, it is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly programming related and rather asks for a security assessment of slicing a part of the RSA ciphertext off to get an IV. It's much better suited for [crypto.se].

Answer (score 1):

**RSA** encrypts one block of data into one block of encrypted data. The size of the data that can fit in a block is dictated by the key size. The size of the encrypted block is not dependent on how much data you encrypt, but of the key size. So removing the **IV** from the **RSA** input won't make the output smaller - assuming that the input can fit in one block. The presence of an **IV** in the **RSA** block won't have an impact on the total encryption time.

From a security point of view, you don't need to protect the **IV**. Usually you would just pass it along with the data in clear. Something like this:

```
RSA_Block{
   AES key
   Other things
}
AES_Block{
   IV
   Data
}
```

I know this actually makes the data a bit bigger. But it won't have much impact on the time for processing. Considering the cost of memcpy when talking about **RSA** encryption don't make any sense. There is more than a factor 1000 in difference [(might even be in the millions - depending on key size etc.)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/rsa-4096-bit-key-benchmark).

Comment: Thanks! I should repraise my question. Since I was also concern on the space the IV takes if I put it outside the RSA block. So I came out with the idea of "use the RSA encoded block as IV". It works for me, I want to know if it is secure or not...